# Failed to automatically create UIAlertAction obj by traversing a dictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, dictionary, block, traversal

I found that creating each `UIAlertAction` for my `UIAlertController` is too much work so I tried to use a dictionary with its key to create all the actions but didn't work.

Here is my dictionary:

```
- (NSDictionary *)inputActions
{
    static NSDictionary *actions = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        actions = @{@(BLGradeTypeGPA): @"GPA",
                    @(BLGradeTypeGRE): @"GRE",
                    @(BLGradeTypeIELTS): @"IELTS",
                    @(BLGradeTypeSAT): @"SAT",
                    @(BLGradeTypeSSAT): @"SSAT",
                    @(BLGradeTypeTOEFL): @"TOEFL",
                    @(BLGradeTypeGMAT): @"GMAT"};
    });
    return actions;
}
```

And I coded the action creating here:

```
[inputActions enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id  _Nonnull key, id  _Nonnull obj, BOOL * _Nonnull stop)
{
    NSString *title = [inputActions valueForKey:key];
    UIAlertAction *inputAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:title style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * _Nonnull action)
    {
        NSNumber *num = key;
        BLGradeType type = num.integerValue;
        if ([weakSelf checkDuplicateWithGradeType:type])
        {
            [weakSelf loadDuplicatGradeTypeAlert];
        }
        else
        {
            [weakSelf gradeTypeSelectedForGradeCell:cell withGradeType:type];
        }
    }];
    [ac addAction:inputAction];
}];
```

But it would generate the following error when I trigger the relevant method to present the `UIAlertController`:

```
[__NSCFNumber length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xb000000000000003
(null)
((
0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000018269ee50 <redacted> + 148
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000181d03f80 objc_exception_throw + 56
2   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001826a5ccc <redacted> + 0
3   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001826a2c74 <redacted> + 872
4   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001825a0d1c _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 92
5   Foundation                          0x0000000182f91f94 <redacted> + 44
6   BankwelLiuxue                       0x00000001002a2a84 __72-[BLGradeInputViewController loadGradeOptionAlertSheetForGradeTypeCell:]_block_invoke + 112
7   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001825ea50c <redacted> + 88
8   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001825d8184 <redacted> + 180
9   BankwelLiuxue                       0x00000001002a2898 -[BLGradeInputViewController loadGradeOptionAlertSheetForGradeTypeCell:] + 364
10  BankwelLiuxue                       0x00000001002a3e08 -[BLGradeInputViewController gradeInputTableViewCell:didTapGradeType:] + 104
11  BankwelLiuxue                       0x00000001002ebb50 -[BLGradeInputTableViewCell gradeTypeLabelTapped:] + 104
12  UIKit                               0x0000000187d79c8c <redacted> + 164
13  UIKit                               0x000000018798e5dc <redacted> + 172
14  UIKit                               0x000000018781b688 <redacted> + 784
15  UIKit                               0x0000000187d7b28c <redacted> + 72
16  UIKit                               0x00000001877da3d8 <redacted> + 372
17  UIKit                               0x00000001877d7154 <redacted> + 2404
18  UIKit                               0x00000001878194f8 <redacted> + 1132
19  UIKit                               0x0000000187818af4 <redacted> + 764
20  UIKit                               0x00000001877e8f4c <redacted> + 248
21  UIKit                               0x00000001877e7528 <redacted> + 6568
22  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000182655124 <redacted> + 24
23  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000182654bb8 <redacted> + 540
24  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001826528b8 <redacted> + 724
25  CoreFoundation                      0x000000018257cd10 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 384
26  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000183e64088 GSEventRunModal + 180
27  UIKit                               0x0000000187851f70 UIApplicationMain + 204
28  BankwelLiuxue                       0x0000000100294eec main + 124
29  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000018211a8b8 <redacted> + 4
)
```

I even tried `for...in` to traverse the keys in the dictionary but still the same error.

It was able to go to the line:

```
UIAlertAction *inputAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:title style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * _Nonnull action)
```

But instead of getting into the handler block, it crashes.

Comment: which line it gives the error ?

Comment: @Shubhank It was able to go to this line `UIAlertAction *inputAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:title style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * _Nonnull action)` but could not go into the block part and crashed.

Comment: [weakSelf checkDuplicateWithGradeType:type] what it contains ?

Comment: @PKT I can paste the code here but do you think it is relevant? Cause the program seems not to be able to get to that line of code. It just calls to present another `UIAlertController` to warn that you picked duplicated option.

Comment: as per my thinking error says that you are trying to get Length of integer object  which might be not allowed so search **length** keyboard in xcode and try to debug with all exception breakpoint